# Covariance structure of a 3-level hierarchical model with random slope and intercept

Tags: covariance, multilevel-analysis

I would like someone to confirm if I am getting correctly the covariance matrix in a 3 level mixed model with random slope and intercept. I have random intercepts at level 2 and 3 and a random slope at level 2.

Here is the model: 
[image]

The total variance should be:

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: I have just replicated a paper (Kim and Frees, 2007, "Multilevel Modelling with Correlated Effects", Psychometrika, 72(4), 505-533) that uses this type of covariance matrix structure and I get the same results...thus the formula is correct.